# Cassandra migration

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

I have Cassandra 0.8.0 running with data on server 1, and a clean install of Cassandra 1.0.3 on server 2.

Is it possible to just copy some files from server 1 to server 2? Or do i have to write my own import/export code?

Both servers can be taken down, restarted, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you not upgrade server1? Upgrade details here (either way read this first):
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cassandra/branches/cassandra-1.0/NEWS.txt?view=markup

But if you do want to change machines, follow the procedures for 'nodetool snapshot' as detailed here:
http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Backing_up_data

Re-create the schema on the new node, then add the snapshots to the data directory (as described above), restart cassandra then issue a nodetool scrub.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zznate it had to do with hardware.

Here some links i found useful:

http://jonathanhui.com/cassandra-data-maintenance-backup-and-system-recovery
 http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration
 http://www.memonic.com/user/pneff/folder/database/id/1bZvk

**If it looks like nothing happened after migrating make sure you create the column family's on the new node using CassandraCli.**